# SQLCMD - add date to CSV. When run inside Command Prompt it works, when in Job then %date

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, csv, sqlcmd, date

I've been battling for hours to add a date to a CSV name:
For brevity, Im just taking the first character of the date here.

In SQL Command, this works:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -E -W -w 999 -s "," -Q "SELECT D.* FROM sys.databases D" -o "C:\sqlcmd%date:~1,1%.csv"
```

But when I try to use that exact same code inside the step of a job, the filename is

```
sqlcmd_%date
```

I cant run xp_commandShell, is there a way to get the dynamic date working in SQLCmd please?
I've read through so many articles, [eg](http://sqlandme.com/2013/04/12/sql-server-add-datetime-to-output-file-of-bcp-sqlcmd-2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Agent Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx) instead, eg

```
sqlcmd -S .\sql2012 -d master -E -W -w 999 -s "," -Q "SELECT D.* FROM sys.databases D" -o "c:\temp\sqlcmd$(ESCAPE_NONE(DATE)).csv"
```

This worked for me.  Just a reminder, bcp is a more appropriate tool for this kind of extract; you won't have the header and "row(s) affected" problems which you're not dealing with here.

Comment: You just saved me from having to enable xp_cmdShell. Thank you so much!